# How apple devices recognise that an open wifi requires credentials

Tags: ios, wifi

Sorry for the title, but I don't fully know how to ask this questions, and I do think it's related to programming.

If you have an apple mobile device, and you walk into a place that has an open wifi (such as many on the coffee chains or airports), and you try to use the Internet, a screen appears asking for the credentials to use the Internet. This screen is not in safari, but ios recognises that it needs a password to access the internet and displays this *screen*. In the UK, BT open zone does this.

I'm wondering how the apple device recognise this. Is it a standard? (I haven't seen this on android devices). I've tried googling this, but I couldn't find anything (probably because I don't fully know what to search for)

Just in case, I'm **not** talking about a secure wifi, that requires a password.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Apple, but Windows 8 apparently tries to connect to one of Microsoft's web servers and verifies if this works.

Comment: And what does it do if the page that comes back is a login page from the Internet service provider?